# Spring - multiple configurations and @CompontentScan order

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have multiple Spring `@Configuration` classes that define beans. The main class where I run application has `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = BasePackage.class)`.

My question, what is the order these components are scanned and beans are created?

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = BasePackage.class)
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And configurations

```
@Configuration
class Config1{
    // defines beans
}

@Configuration
class Config2{
    // defines beans
}
```

Another maven dependency also has `Config3`

```
@Configuration
class Config3{
    // defines beans
}
```

I tried to search the documentation, but I did not find which order these components are scanned and initialized.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html

### Update

I asked this question because I have a bean that has @ConditionalOnMissingBean, and multiple configurations that define it. Where is in the official documentation statement, which order `@Configuration` classes are scanned.

Comment: Though not answer to your query but a note : @Order.. annotation could be used to control the  load sequence

Comment: Agree, but if no @Order, how does Spring define order?

Answer (score 0):

In a first step Spring scans all classes relative to your base package for beans. Then spring will create the beans and inject it.

If you need to have the beans created in certain order you can do so by adding `@DependsOn`

From the docs:

> The depends-on attribute can explicitly force one or more beans to be
>   initialized before the bean using this element is initialized.