# How to autowire FactoryBeans in an Actuator Endpoint

Tags: java, spring

I would like to know whether there are any best practices or standard patterns for autowiring factory beans themselves in Spring.

I am working with [`StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/api/org/springframework/kafka/config/StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.html) which implements `SmartLifecycle`. In order to start and stop Streams at runtime, I implemented an actuator endpoint that autowires a `private Map<String, StreamsBuilderFactoryBean> topologyFactories`. Note, that I need the actual `FactoryBean`, not the object it creates. There seems to be an issue with the instantiation order. The `Map` is empty because Spring seems to instantiate the actuator endpoint before the FactoryBeans.

I worked around this by calling

```
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void onReady() {
        this.topologyFactories = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext()
                .getBeansOfType(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.class);
    }
```

and basically, autowire "a second time".

From [Spring - multiple configurations and @CompontentScan order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494641/spring-multiple-configurations-and-compontentscan-order) I could annotate the actuator class with `@DependsOn`, but then I would need to list every single `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` and maintain this.

It "feels" like there should be a better way and I am probably just missing some knowledge about the bean lifecycle.

Comment: Do you really need a `Map<String, StreamBuilderFactoryBean>`? Or do you only need the instances? If the latter you can use an `ObjectProvider<StreamBuilderFactoryBean>` and use the `iterator` or `stream` method to iterate over them.